# Why does it take a long time to connect to my local site?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, home-networking, localhost

I have Windows 7 and a local website on Apache / PHP. I have the most recent versions installed.

I have some PCs connected into a local network by the router, which assigns local IP addresses like `192.168.1.x` to the computers.

When I access it from my own PC at `http://127.0.0.1/` it loads instantly.

But if I access it by a local IP address, like `http://192.168.1.120/`, it connects significantly more slowly, and may even take up to 20 secs.

Both the server itself and local PCs show this same behavior (are equally slow) when accessing the site via a local IP address.

So any ideas what's wrong with it?

**--EDIT--**

Well, thanks to the suggestion I've checked my ServerName var in appache. After setting it to 192.168.1.120 (the address by which I actually make my requests) I noticed an improvement. It would connect me almost instantly, but if I'm inactive for about a minute or less, it gets me waiting again to connect to my local site for about 10 secs.

I still don't know what is be causing it, and if you have some ideas you are welcome to contribute. :-)

Comment: What do you have as the ServerName in the Apache configuration file?

Comment: Oh, the ServerName is not set, and I actually do get the following notice each time I launch it: `AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::e40d:590:fd75:d301. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: I've just set it `192.168.1.120` and loads fast now again. Lots of thanks! :-)

Comment: Though, if I'm being inactive for about a minute, it would get me waiting up to 10 secs upon refreshing the page.

Comment: It would be good if you update your question with the gathered information (if you still are not happy with the result) or write an answer yourself and accept it (which is totaly ok).

Comment: Well, I've discovered an improvement, but taking up to 10 seconds to connect to my own machine is a bit ridiculous, so I would still listen to some advice (if anyone had something similar).

Comment: My suggestion is that after a certain time of inactivity windows simply clears some cache and has to reload files from harddisk instead of RAM.

Comment: I know, but my machine is fast enough to load it up in instant as long as the hard disk is spinning. And even more so if I open it from `http://127.0.0.1` it is ready to load up in some fractions of a second, and I mean anytime. I've had this for six month, and I've been never experiencing any problems if I open it through the local host. But when I tried calling it from my network address - `192.168.1.120` it acts quite abnormally, if I stop hitting the 'refresh' and give it some 30-60 sec wait.

Answer (score 0):

The timeouts, working then non-working and other characteristics suggest duplicate IP Addresses on the network or some problem with ARP. Check the ARP table both when the web site is coming up and when it's being delayed by listing the entries.

```
ARP -a 192.168.1.120
```